# I've hosted ILB ASE, but it's not reachable from my browser. Ho do I reach it?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I've hosted ILB ASE and configured DNS for it, but it shows site not rechable. ILB ASEs can be accessed from vNet. So how do I reach it?

Answer (score 0):

One way to get it to be available on Internet will be to use Azure Application Gateway.
Otherwise it will be available thru hosts within vNet.

Comment: I created a VM in VNET and browsed the app hosted on ILB ASE in the browser. Both site and scm were reached.

Comment: You are correct, it will be accessible from any VMs within the VNET. but not from outside VNET or external internet. If you want it available thru Internet then Application Gateway is one of choice.

Answer (score 0):

The interest of having an ILB ASE is to host applications on a private (internal) network). You have different ways for users to connect to your application:

1. VPN - Connecting private network to Azure
2. Reverse proxy (eg. Application Gateway, Nginx) - Configure a public interface/name resolution for users to connect to application. The proxy sends back the traffic to the internal network (look for net peering, if the resource is deployed on different vNets)